# jekyll-docs failing after install

Tags: jekyll

This is my first question, so be cool, mkay?

I have jekyll 3.3.1 installed, and jekyll-docs 3.3.0 seems to be the latest version. 'jekyll docs' fails with 'You must install the 'jekyll-docs' gem to use the 'jekyll docs' command.' I have installed jekyll-docs, so I'm not sure what the problem is. My research has indicated that jekyll and jekyll-docs need to be the same version in order to function properly.

Can anyone weigh in on this? Thank you!

SK